# Get the items in a ListView in thread via a class

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, exception

I have a class and in that I have a function "Build", the class takes a parameter: "ListView lstFiles". And when .Build is called, it iterates through each item in the listview and processes it.

When I try to do this, I get the error " Cross thread access violation "

My code:

```
foreach (ListViewItem item in lstFiles.Items)
{
    // Processing here
}
```

I tried getting the items as described here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171728%28VS.80%29.aspx

I need to get each item in the ListView and process it

Can any one please help ?

Comment: how is the code being fired?  Is this code executed from another thread you created prior?

Comment: This code is being fired by a class ( a separate class ).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use delegate to solve cross thread problems.  For e.g.

```
    delegate ListView.ListViewItemCollection DelGetItems(ListView lvControl);

    ListView.ListViewItemCollection GetItems(ListView lvControl)
    {
        if (lvControl.InvokeRequired)
        {
            return (ListView.ListViewItemCollection)lvControl.Invoke(new DelGetItems(GetItems) ,new Object[] { lvControl });
        }
        else
        {
            return lvControl.Items;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I tweaked your code (as I can't use "this.Invoke"), still getting a null value. Remember that i am using a class and then calling the Build method. The class has a constructor which takes the name of the ListView as a param.